# How to compare a mean with a mean of a means

Tags: mean, dependent-variable, analysis-of-means

For each patient, I have the value of a blood parameter on admission and several values of that blood parameter in subsequent days (not all the patients have the same number of posterior measurements).

I want to compare the initial value of the 100 patients I have, with the means of the over 30 values per patient in the following days after admission.

Data are dependent, but I do not know how to proceed because I want to compare a mean (the starting value of 100 patients) with a mean of a mean (the mean of over 30 subsequent measures after admission for each of the 100 patients). How can I proceed in SPSS?

Comment: 1. This question seems predicated on the implicit assumption that the measurements taken after the admission one will all have the same population mean. Is that so? It's best to make it explicit. (If it's not so, presumably there's a tendency to some sort of curvilinear trend, in which case, what is the average supposed to be estimating?)  2. Further, are you assuming the post-admission measurements all have the same standard deviation? 3. Are you assuming the measured values (within subject) to be independent over time? 4. Are you making any distributional assumptions (at least approximately)

Comment: 1. No, they will not have the same population mean. We think the the initial parameter is altered and, with time, i will tend to normalize. The average value toward is tending is the normal value. 2. No, we think that they are not, because our guess is that the value is disturbed and getting normal with time. 3 No, they are dependent, because they are evolving to the normal value. 4 The parameter is normal in the normal population. Thanks

Comment: 1. Then averaging different numbers of followup values for different subjects will be estimating *different* quantities for each of them - not a consistent comparison. You will probably need some sort of model for what's going on over time so that you can relate observations over time and you need to very carefully specify what it is about this function that you want to compare with the initial value. (By the way, avoid using 'parameter' when you mean 'variable'; the word *parameter* has a specific meaning in statistics you don't intend and this is likely to lead people into confusion.) ...ctd

Comment: ctd ... 2. You think it's likely that the standard deviation is larger for the initial observation and then reduces? 3. Be careful not to conflate "trend in the mean" with "correlated deviations about the trend". 4. It literally *can't* actually be normal. Do you mean that the normal is a commonly used model for it? That seems slightly surprising since it's at least possible for an SBP to go from 100 to say 205 in a hypertensive crisis, but it's *impossible* for it to decrease by the same amount (to -5 !).  Consequently, it would be expected to be at least *somewhat* right skewed.